# Error in fda_fetch: Too Many Requests (RFC 6585) (HTTP 429)

Tags: api

I am getting this error while having some tests with https://github.com/jonathanglevine/openfdashinyapps

What is the limit of requests per day?
If I provide account info with secret and token would I have the same limit of requests?

Comment: https://open.fda.gov/apis/authentication/